# Is an orthonormal eigenbase of an observable Hamel or Schauder?

Tags: hilbert-space, quantum-information, observables

Suppose $\mathcal{H}$ is an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, and let $A$ be an observable. The quantum system is prepared in a state $\vert \Psi \rangle$. After measuring the observable the state $\vert \Psi \rangle$ collapses into one of the eigenvectors $\vert \Psi_i \rangle$ of the observable, and its corresponding eigenvalue is the measured value.

Now if we consider the set $\{ \vert \Psi_i \rangle \vert i \in I \}$ of the orthonormal eigenbase of $A$, my question is: is the notion "eigenbase" used in the sense of a *Hamel* base or in the sense of a *Schauder* base ?

Comment: Is your latter set the eigenvectors corresponding to a single eigenvalue of $A$, or corresponding to the full spectrum of $A$?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer: corresponding to the full spectrum of $A$.

Comment: Then generally Schauder basis.